# Unable to use React context

Tags: reactjs, mobx, react-context, mobx-react

I am unable to use React context when I import context from a different file. i.e when i try to print store.bugs in BugsList.js file. I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bugs' of undefined`.

However when I put them together (as shown in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnhIJA64ByY)) in one file it works (see below code). In my case I would like to import StoreProvider and use it as shown in BugsList.js file

**index.js** file

```
import { StoreProvider } from "./StoreProvider";
import BugsList from "./BugsList";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <StoreProvider>
        <BugsList />
      </StoreProvider>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**BugsList.js** file

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocalStore, useObserver } from "mobx-react";
import { StoreProvider } from "./StoreProvider";
const StoreContext = React.createContext();

const BugsList = () => {
  const store = React.useContext(StoreContext);
  console.log(store.bugs); // I get error Cannot read property 'bugs' of undefined

  return useObserver(() => (
    <>
      <h1>{store.bugsCount} Bugs!</h1>
      <p>{store.bugs}</p>
    </>
  ));
};
```

**StoreProvider.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocalStore, useObserver } from "mobx-react";
const StoreContext = React.createContext();

export const StoreProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const store = useLocalStore(() => ({
    bugs: ["Centipede"],
    addBug: (bug) => {
      store.bugs.push(bug);
    },
    get bugsCount() {
      return store.bugs.length;
    }
  }));

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

However when I put them together in one file it works.

**In onefile**

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocalStore, useObserver } from "mobx-react";
const StoreContext = React.createContext();

const StoreProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const store = useLocalStore(() => ({
    bugs: ["Centipede"],
    addBug: (bug) => {
      store.bugs.push(bug);
    },
    get bugsCount() {
      return store.bugs.length;
    }
  }));

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};

const BugsList = () => {
  const store = React.useContext(StoreContext);
  console.log(store.bugs); // This prints the bugs list

  return useObserver(() => (
    <>
      <h1>{store.bugsCount} Bugs!</h1>
      <p>{store.bugs}</p>
    </>
  ));
};


const MobxTest = () => {
  return (
    <StoreProvider>
      <BugsList />
    </StoreProvider>
  );
};

export default MobxTest;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `StoreContext` from `BugsList.js` inside your `StoreProvider.js`.

```js
// StoreProvider.js
import React from "react";

export const StoreContext = React.createContext();
...
```

```js
// BugsList.js
import React from "react";
import { StoreContext } from "./StoreProvider";

export default BugsList = () => {
  const store = React.useContext(StoreContext);
  console.log(store.bugs);

  ...
};
```

[image: Edit sleepy-gates-kvnbo]

Comment: +1, but for clarity, @user44776 the issue you're running into is that you're creating multiple contexts. Bertdida's solution here solves that by exporting a single instance of context and sharing it across components.